# Whither module not found

Tags: python3, pip

I am a Python beginner and have some use or the 'whither' module. I did `pip install --user whither`, which installed it successfully (or so pip says). However, in the Python interpreter, `import whither` results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whither'
```

Do I need to do something else too?

I am on Python 3.8.4.

Thanks!

Comment: What OS (and what version) are you using? Are you using `python` or `python3`? If you're using `python3`, you may need to use `pip3` (because if `python` is Python 2, then `pip` is probably for Python 2). What's the output of `pip --version` ?

Comment: Gentoo, kernel 5.8.0rc-7, Python 3.8.4, Pip 20.0.2